# QCA9565 / AR9565 Slow at some distance

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, ubuntu-14.04, dell-inspiron

I'm having trouble with an Dell Inspiron 14 5447 Wifi using Ubuntu 14.04.
It's an QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter.

When I'm at 4 meters distance of my wireless router, it works fine, as seen below (my contracted network is 35Mbps down 3.5Mbps up):

[image]

But when I'm at something about 10 meters of my router, the download speed drops dramatically, but by some reason, the Upload Speed is relatively normal.

[image]

With many other devices, even with an Asus Vivobook notebook, I can reach something about 20-25Mbps speed at the same distance...

I've already tried to recompile the athk9 driver; Tried the nowcrypt solution; But nothing seems to fix it;

Comment: Have you tried using a different wifi channel? Perhaps that particular adapter is more sensitive to interference than others.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use all channels avaliable in the configuration of my wireless router, but nothing changes...

Comment: It appears to be a dual band adapter; are you using 2.4GHz or 5.0GHz? Have you tried switching? What band are the devices that perform well using?

Comment: I'm using an 2.4GHz... All of my devices are performing with this frequency

Comment: Do you have a different adapter to try with in that same machine temporarily, or can you obtain one? E.g. a USB wifi adapter. If you try different Atheros / non-Atheros adapters perhaps you can narrow down the cause.

Comment: I didn't tried with an external adapter... I'll try to find one here and see what happens

Comment: Have you eliminated hardware issues? (I.e. Does this wifi router work better/okay with another, OS?)